# Multiplying 'generated' column in SQL

Tags: sql, replit

**Fairly new to SQL, working with an auction database. Trying to get the 'tix_spend' column to be 3x the 'no_of_tix' (each ticket costs £3) - the SUM I've put in seems to be working on some of the values but not others?**

**I then need to add the tix_spend to the bid_spend to get a total spend, if anyone can help with that too!**

SELECT bi.BidderID, bi.FirstName || ' ' || bi.Lastname AS bidder_name,

t.Quantity AS no_of_tix,

SUM(t.Quantity*3) AS tix_spend,

b.BidAmount AS bid_spend

FROM Bidder bi

JOIN Tickets t ON t.BidderID = bi.BidderID

JOIN Bids b ON b.BidderID = bi.BidderID

GROUP BY b.BidderID

ORDER BY bidder_name

LIMIT 5;

**The result I'm getting is:**

BidderID|bidder_name|no_of_tix|tix_spend|bid_spend

38|Adam  Page|9|27|140

6|Alice  Carson|1|30|175 ---- (eg what's happening here? I've tried to multiply 1* 3 and got 30?)

14|Angelina  Cobb|10|30|235

35|Armando  Norman|9|27|78

58|Bobby  Walton|1|33|125 --- (not what I would expect either)

Comment: Hi, can you verify that you're using MySQL as you DBMS? If so I would add the MySQL tag. Also some example data of what you are querying exactly would be very helpful in finding the solution correctly.

Comment: Please format the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with MySQL, but in MSSQL that query you provided won't work because your group by clause isn't correct.

Also, not sure what you are trying to accomplish with SUM(t.Quantity*3)?

I think what you need is as simple as:

```
SELECT bi.BidderID, bi.FirstName || ' ' || bi.Lastname AS bidder_name,

t.Quantity AS no_of_tix,

t.Quantity*3 AS tix_spend,

(t.Quantity*3) + b.BidAmount AS bid_spend

FROM Bidder bi

JOIN Tickets t ON t.BidderID = bi.BidderID

JOIN Bids b ON b.BidderID = bi.BidderID

ORDER BY bidder_name

LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: To add, I am a total novice and thought you needed SUM to do any arithmetic... good to know that's not the case

Comment: @Lou Perfect! If you confirm the solution please check this answer as the correct one and close the post so the community knows. And fair enough, glad you cleared that up :)! Enjoy SQLing!